# User does not have write access to all folders

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, virtual-machine

Trying to start a program through the Terminal within my Ubuntu 20.04 VM (Oracle VirtualBox) and I am getting this error:

[warn] - No write permissions at '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu'

[error] - Your user does not have write access to all folders. Exiting.

I tried doing:
sudo chown -R user /etc/
but this didn't work...

Note: This is a brand new VM I installed today.

Comment: Don't trash the permissions of `/etc`. Instead, give the program the appropriate permissions, for example by using `sudo` to run it.

Comment: Ok! I tried running sudo with it however it just gave me:


sudo: vserver: command not found